# Using React Hook with Context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I do a little login page. 
I would like to separe views and controller.
So I use Context

```
const axios = require('axios');

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

const onLogin = (login, password, saveCredentials) => {
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [authentified, setAuthentified] = useState("");
axios.post('/signin', {
    username: login,
    password: password
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (saveCredentials)
    {
        var cred = {
                user: response.data.username,
                password: response.data.password
                };
    }
    console.log("test : " + response);
    setAuthentified(true) ;
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    setError(err.response.data.message);

   })
}
const AuthProvider = props =>
(
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
                onLogin
          }}>
        {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
);

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

views :

```
import { AuthContext } from 'controllers/authContext'
export default function Login(props) {
const classes = useStyles();
const Auth = useContext(AuthContext);
...
{ !Auth.authentified ? (
<Button simple size="lg" color="primary" onClick={() => Auth.useLogin(login, password)}>Login</Button>
               </CardFooter>
                <p align="center">{Auth.error}</p>
) : null
```

But I can not use state into context function, it's not a react function.
The error message is : `React Hook "useState" is called in function "onLogin" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

How I can use state, and call them, into Login component ?

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use the react methods (`hooks`) the same way as you are using it right now , Just make sure you are importing things currently. I think there is a import error in your upper file, use should either use

```
import {useState} from 'react'
```

And keep your code same
or replace every **`useState`** with **`React.useState`**.

Comment: I use `import {useState} from 'react'`. I don't put full code, just the portion which give error

Comment: @vana please post the error to have a better insight